# Get the latest value from EventEmitter of angular/core

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have one of the variables in the service class as

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() openReportsSidePanel: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

From the other component, the value is emitted to this variable

```
  viewReportsSidePanel(value) {
        this.openReportsSidePanel.emit(value);
    }
```

I am trying to get the last emitted value

```
const lastValue = from(this._assessmentResponseDataService.openReportsSidePanel.pipe(takeLast(1)).toPromise());
        lastValue.subscribe((value)=>  console.log(value));
```

Not able to get the value in the console, however, if I remove the takeLast(1)

```
this._assessmentResponseDataService.openReportsSidePanel.subscribe(value=>  console.log(value));
```

Now it prints two value False and true, since emitted the two value, however I need to get only the last emitted value that is True.

1. If the emit value is FALSE , FALSE , then I need to take the last FALSE
2. If the emit value is TRUE, TRUE, then I need to take the last TRUE
3. If the emit value is TRUE, FALSE , then I need to take the last FALSE
4. If the emit value is FALSE , TRUE, then I need to take the last TRUE

I have a another HTTP call, and it should get called only once

Comment: [takeLast](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeLast) only emits after the source has completed. If you only want to handle `true`, use `filter` or add logic to the handler.

Comment: @molnarm No it is not related to the TRUE and FALSE I need to get only the last value

Comment: Something is really unclear in this question. If you create a **minimal** repro on Stackblitz, preferably with no context whatsoever to your app, just pinpoint your issue to have the minimal amount of code needed, I'll do my best to help you out.